# initiallizing float array C

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I work in Code Composer Studio Version: 6.0.1.00040 with the card LCDK C6748.

but I think it's a general C question.

I have a global float array, initiallized like this:

```
float prn_buff[BUFF_NOISE_SIZE]={0};       // pseudo random noise
// I expected that the array will be full of zeros (appearantly it is not)
```

from some reason, I noticed, that when I set a breakpoint the array is full of NaN's.
Is the initiallization wrong?
or I should be looking for something else?

I set the BP inside the main(), the array is initiallized before the main(),
maybe I misunderstand something, but when I get inside the main(), isn't it after all global variables has been initiallized?

Comment: Considering the answer to a similar question to yours, http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/3627 , Code Composer Studio is not a C compiler. The C standard is clear on the effect of `float prn_buff[BUFF_NOISE_SIZE]={0};` (for a global array you don't even need the `= { 0 };`). Since Code Composer Studio is not a C compiler, you should not ask here with the tag C, where you will only get answers like Lundin's, but look for answers in Code Composer Studio's documentation or on forums dedicated to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong in the given code. See the code example below

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFF_NOISE_SIZE 10

float prn_buff[BUFF_NOISE_SIZE]={0}; // Global array of floats 

int main()
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<BUFF_NOISE_SIZE;i++){
        printf("%f \n",prn_buff[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
0.000000                                                                                                                                                                        
0.000000                                                                                                                                                                        
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the initiallization wrong? or I should be looking for something else?

The initialization is fine, it sets all items of the array to `0.0f`. The problem is likely elsewhere in your code. Or perhaps you are setting the breakpoint too early, before the array initialization has been executed.